# Does it make sense to speak of amplitudes of finite closed boundaries in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-interpretations

A example of amplitude in Relativistic Quantum Mechanics or specifically in QFT is the amplitude of a field configuration on a space-like hyper-surface of space-time to "lead" to another field configuration on another space-like hyper-surface of space-time. In the path-integral picture one simply integrates over all possible field configurations on the interior, giving each a weight in the normal way. Now if one wants to generalize this to finite closed boundaries, we would get an amplitude for each field configuration on a finite closed boundary of space-time. but how would we interpret this? This question relates to interpretations of quantum mechanics, has anyone investigated this line ?

Comment: Actually in QFT (at least in particle physics) one usually calculates the amplitude between two spatial slices which are infinitely separated in time, i.e. the S-matrix. The infinite separation is needed to make the asymptotic state be Fock-like particles. Real time-dependent QFT (sometimes used in condensed matter) requires some very imaginative formulation of the path integral (see Keldysh formalism). I think what you're asking about has been pondered mostly by quantum gravity people, who have this problem in spades. See works by Rovelli.

Comment: @genneth I think you should post your very informative comments as an answer.

Comment: @genneth: This is not completely true--- it is true for S-matrix calculations, but the original pure field theory calculations of Schwinger, which were based on Feynman's path integral (in Schwinger's action principle reformulation) were between two finite time hypersurfaces, and this is still the cleanest way theoretically. The S-matrix thing was only in response to the quest for a pure S-matrix theory, which quantum field theory isn't.

Comment: @RonMaimon: agreed; the OP went with path integrals, and in that case finite separation is more complex. I do indeed prefer the operator based approach --- amplitudes are conceptually clear and path integrals are just a way to calculate them. However, in genuinely strong GR regimes where two disjoint Cauchy surfaces aren't possible, one doe have to work much harder to find a consistent interpretation of the amplitudes.

Comment: @RonMaimon So I am still confused, So Is the calculation betweeen two finite hypersurfaces the accepted theoretical way ? and if so has anyone investigated the calculation with finite closed boundaries?

Comment: @MohamedAlaaElBehairy: I will post an answer--- yes, for non S-matrix field theory, this is a fine process, but it requires a field definition/renormalization limiting procedure. The closed surface business is done in imaginary time for various reasons, but it is often unphysical in real time, but there are exceptions. The best source on this is 1950s Schwinger, who is very formal and not read as much today as he should be. I'll get to doing an answer at some point.

Comment: @RonMaimon: perhaps I'm misunderstanding the thrust of the question or your comment, but I think the OP wants to know whether it is possible and what it would mean to assign an amplitude to a field configuration defined on the boundary of a *spacetime* hypervolume, i.e. including time-like parts of the boundary. I wasn't aware that there was anything done on this formalism outside of quantum gravity circles?

Comment: @genneth: It's ok in the Path integral wihen the hypervolume is always bounded by spacelike sheets--- these can enclose a volume completely even when they are never timelike pointed. Schwinger does this all the time, and defines the stress energy tensor of the field theory by these spacelike-bounded hypervolumes, this is the essence of the Schwinger Action principle from the 1950s (it's really just the path integral in disguise, because Candlin hadn't yet invented Grassman integration). If you have spacelike parts, you can give this meaning too, in terms of clamped fields on the boundary.

Comment: @RonMaimon: but I think that's the whole point of the OP's question --- what to do about the timelike (I assume that's what you meant to write in the last sentence) parts of the boundary, and what the resulting amplitude means. Mohamed should correct me if I has mis-understood.

Comment: @genneth Yes, that is the thrust of my question. What to do about the time-like parts? Did anybody do any work on this formalism? and what is the physical interpretation of such amplitude?

Comment: @MohamedAlaaElBehairy: Oh, if that is the question, there is a problem, because you need to specify the field values on the time-like parts, and in this case, you are not getting a transition amplitude, but a transition amplitude with a field clamped to certain values on the time-like portions.

Answer (score 2):

A wave functional of a field A is $\Psi[A]$. This is the amplitude that there is a certain field configuration A. (Compare to ordinary quantum mechanics where a wave function $\psi(x)$ is the amplitude for a particle to be at position x). If a wave function is highly peaked at a particular value it means that this value is most likely. Similary a wave functional of a field A can be highly peaked at a certain field configuration f. It may be a Gaussian such as

$$\Psi[A] = \exp\left(-\int (A(x)-f(x))^2 dx^3 \right)$$

(This only works for bosons. Fermions don't have anything corresponding to a classical field).

The universe at any time is described by the wave functional of the fields (which may be highly peaked at a particular field configuration... or not). The amplitude that the universe will have a different wave functional $\Psi_{out}$ at a later time is given by the path integral:

$$\Delta[\Psi_{in},\Psi_{out}] = \int \Psi_{in}[A]\Psi_{out}[A]e^{i S[A] } D[A]$$

One can calculate this by expanding the wave functional in terms of particle amplitudes:

$$ \Psi_{in}[A] = a + \int\psi(x)A(x,t_{in})dx^3 + \int\psi(x,y)A(x,t_{in})A(y,t_{in})dx^3dy^3+...$$

Where $\psi(x,y)$ is the amplitude for particles being found at both positions x and y. In particular we have:

$$ \Delta_F(x,y) = \int A(x) A(y) e^{i S[A] } D[A]$$

which is the amplitude for a particle to travel from x to y.

As for closed boundaries, the time slice for the incoming data and the time slice for the outgoing data can be joined at the boundaries forming a nut shape.